# Responsive image grid - 3 images, 1 left 2 stacked right

Tags: css, responsive-design

Ok, so here is where I am at:
http://www.discountramps.com/powersport-products/c/BRAND-BW/

Thanks for all your help so far. Something with my percentages or something seems off. When I resize the browser, the images break. I would like them to just scale until it hits the media query. Does this make any sense?

Thanks again for any help in advance!!!
- Allen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Sorry I thought about that after I uploaded the images. I did have a start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible layout for your question, now play with it.

```css
/*colors*/

.black {
  background: black
}
.red {
  background: red
}
.green {
  background: green
}
/*layout*/

.black,
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh
}
.red,
.green {
  height: 50vh
}
/* responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .black,
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    float: none
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dippas! This gets me started!

Comment: ok below is where I am. Any help again would be much appreciated. You guys are the best! I am trying to have the images and spacing scale proportionately until it hits mobile view, does that make any sense? The wrapper of where this will be placed is 1130px wide.